# How to prevent ngBlur from firing first

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Supposedly I have an input text markup like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-focus="x = true" ng-blur="x = false">
```

So when you click it, this div shows up:

```
<div ng-show="x === true">
    <ul>
        <li ng-click="choose(1)">First</li>
        <li ng-click="choose(2)">Second</li>
        <li ng-click="choose(3)">Third</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

What happens is when I click one of the selections in the list, the div becomes hidden because the `ng-blur` from the text field is fired, therefore, the `ng-click` in the selection is not executed (or so this is what happens in my situation). Is there any workaround for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of a hack would be to put your `ngBlur`in a `$timeout` pushing it back one digest.

```
<input type="text" ng-focus="x = true" ng-blur="hideFields()">

function hideFields() {
    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.x = false;
    });
}
```

Comment: Cool. I'll try this and report back.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. without a timer in the function, it stills fires faster than the `ng-click`

Comment: With timeout you need to set some delay, blur event always going happens before click, it's not Angular but just how DOM events work.

Comment: Yep now it works now, just added a 3 millisecond delay. I'm accepting this as the answer.

Comment: Note, that 3ms is not reliable, most likely it will depend on browser, so better to set it to like 200ms.

Comment: A `$timeout` without time should probably work too, since the `$timeout` delays the function invocation a digest cycle, letting the `ng-click` go first. @Growlithe this is a dirty hack though, problems like these indicate your design pattern is wrong